# Adding [new { CompanyID = 1}] to [params object[] parameters|, ]but looping it returns Length,LongLength,Rank

Tags: .net, loops, parameters

I want to write a generic handler that can take any parameter for a SQL Command.

I've tried this code:

```
DataTable dt = GetDt("Select * from Company where CompanyID = @CompanyID", new { CompanyID = 1 });
```

which calls this function:

```
public static DataTable GetDt(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
```

and then in this function, it loops through all parameters:

```
        var Params = new List<SqlParameter>();

        foreach (var PropInfo in parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            Params.Add(new SqlParameter(PropInfo.Name, PropInfo.GetValue(parameters, null)));
        }
```

Except, its not getting the PropInfo.Name as "CompanyID", 
its running through a list of Types:

```
[0] Length
[1] LongLength
[2] Rank
[3] Syncroot
[4] IsReadOnly
[5] IsFixedSize
[6] IsSynchronized
```

How can I loop through the list in parameters please?

Comment: You probably don't need the `params` : try with `public static DataTable GetDt(string commandText, object parameters)`

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter is an array of objects (`object[]`) so when you call `GetType().GetProperties()` you're looping through the properties of the *array*, not the properties of the object *in* the array. Try making the parameter a simple `object`, like this:

```
public static DataTable GetDt(string commandText, object parameters)
{
    ...
    foreach (var PropInfo in parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        Params.Add(new SqlParameter(PropInfo.Name, PropInfo.GetValue(parameters, null)));
    }
}
```